# Ассемблерный эквивалент определения нового типа?

Tags: компилятор, ассемблер, c++

```
class MyClass
{
MyClass();
int a;
int b;
void MyMethod();
};
```

Всегда мучал вопрос что делает синтаксический анализатор компилятора языка высокого уровня когда видит такую конструкцию? Записывает описание типа с адресами методов и размерами/типами переменных в какую-то таблицу внутри файла с программой? 
Что происходит при создании объекта класса в стэке?

```
MyClass Object;
```

Из этой таблицы извлекается размеры и типы переменных им назначаются соответствующие адреса, адрес конструктора помещается в стэк вызовов и далее происходит инициализация в зависимости от того что написано в конструкторе?
Где можно почитать подробнее про этот процесс?

Comment: хотите узнать, как все это работает - купите [книгу дракона](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: О спасибо сейчас гляну! 750 страниц, но похоже это исчерпывающие руководство.

Comment: @KoVadim Я прошел по ссылке и с трудом сумел выйти из рекурсии.

Comment: добавлял стандартно, но что то добавило странно. Но по фразе "компиляторы, книга дракона" гуглиться замечательно.

Comment: @KoVadim, у вас в ссылке есть [двоеточие](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/179/хэшкод-ссылка-ведёт-на-ту-же-страницу-на-которой-указана), оттого и не работает — воспользуйтесь каким-нибудь URL shorter'ом.

Comment: да, только я теперь уже не могу редактировать тот комментарий...

Comment: @KoVadim - ссылка ведёт на эту страницу XD

Comment: [Я просто оставлю это здесь][1]


  [1]: http://padabum.com/d.php?id=2169

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В целом, все очень зависит от компилятора. Некоторые умные компиляторы могут даже выбросить  сам класс, если в нем нет необходимости. Но общие принципы все таки есть.

**Начнем**

Когда компилятор видит определение класса, он просто его разбирает. А вот когда  нужно создать экземпляр класса, вот здесь начинается самое интересное. Компилятор, просмотрев описание класса, рассчитывает, сколько нужно под него памяти. В описанном в вопросе классе - минимум 8 байт (здесь и дальше я буду говорить в контексте 32битных платформ x86). По факту - может выделиться больше - например, если класс виртуальный, то ещё от 4 байт для указателя на таблицу виртуальных функций. То есть, в общем виде, new для класса - это просто alloc+memset (а если конструктор не тривиальный, то и вызов конструктора).

Для классов без виртуальных методов память обычно выделяется как под структуру с соответствующими полями. Для виртуальных может быть ещё минимум одно поле.

**А что же такое "методы", они же функции класса?**

это самые обычные функции, просто у них есть ещё один (хотя никто не запрещает компилятору использовать больше, но обычно это один), который по факту является указателем на выделенную ранее память. В методе этот параметр выглядит как this.

**Как происходит обращение к полям:**

Для каждого поля компилятор рассчитывает смещение относительно this. Например, имеем:

```
MyClass m;
m.a = 10;
m.b = 20;
```

На псевдокоде это так

```
mov [this+0], 10
mov [this+4], 20
```

смещение +4, потому что размер int равен 4. Но компилятор может заняться выравниванием и по факту второе поле может оказаться по смещению 8.

**Вызов методов:**

А такой же как и вызов обычных функций. Только, как я писал выше - добавляем ещё один параметр - указатель на класс. Адрес метода компилятор знает.

**Вызов виртуальных методов:**

С ними интереснее. Для этого применяется таблица методов (похоже, что лучше этого пока не придумали. Почитать детальнее можно [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2).) Компилятор по имени функции берет ее индекс в таблице. А когда нужно в коде сделать вызов, то это будет так

```
mov eax, [this+8] ; адрес таблицы методов. 
mov eax, [eax + номер_метода]; загрузили адрес
push параметр
push this
call[eax] ; вызываем функцию по адресу
```

Но компилятор может схитрить. Если он может определить, какой именно метод нужно вызвать, то он может вставить вызов напрямую. Более того, компилятор может не вставлять даже параметра this, если внутри метода оно не используется.

Я думаю, что понятно, что таблицы виртуальных методов создаются по одной на каждый класс, а не на каждый объект.

**Создание объектов на стеке**

а здесь ничего особого. В классической реализации "выделить память на стеке" - это просто изменит указатель вершины стека. Так как стек растет сверху вниз, то это вычитание размера с регистра, хранящего вершину стека. В си даже есть такая функция - alloca (в visual studio может  называться _alloca), которая работает как malloc, но выделяет на стеке.

**абстрактные методы**

Эти методы есть в таблице виртуальных методов, но указывают на специальную функцию, которая отображает сообщение о том, что такие методы нельзя вызывать.

**всякое странное**

В результирующем коде обычно уже нет никаких имен методов и полей. Есть только адреса и смещения. И типов также уже нет. А вот если отладчику нужно показать пользователю данные, то он получает от компилятора специальный map файл, где все это расписано. Именно поэтому, если отлаживать релизный код, то отладчик часто не может даже привязать код к бинарному коду - у него просто нет этой информации. А угадать очень сложно.

Но иногда компиляторы, особенно если они делают отладочный код, могут добавлять дополнительные поля, что бы проверять, что код не делает ничего страшного. Например добавлять реальный тип объекта и сравнивать его при надобности.

А бывает, программист хочет использовать rtti, тут уж нужно подобавлять в каком то виде данных.

Answer (score 4):

Как минимум, происходят три вещи:

1. На стеке выделяется кусок такого размера, чтобы туда гарантированно влез объект.
2. Где-то запоминается тот факт, что при выходе за пределы блока нужно вызвать деструктор.
3. Управление передаётся конструктору.

Никакие размеры и типы внутренних переменных ни из какой таблицы точно не загружаются. Вычисление адресов внутренних переменных происходит во время компиляции кода, который к ним реально обращается. Код, создающий объект, как это ни странно, всего лишь создаёт объект, и не делает ничего другого.

Comment: @Shamov Спасибо, хороший ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сгенерировать ассемблерный листинг из исходника и посмотреть. Если коротко, то компилятор выделяет в стеке память, необходимую для размещения объекта, затем вызывает конструктор и передает ему через `this` адрес ранее выделенной памяти. Как-то так.

Comment: В этом листинге будет 100 килобайт мета информации вроде PE заголовков, кроме того имя класса 100% заменится на какой-нибудь код и я никогда в жизни не найду ничего в этой HEX помойке.

Comment: Странное, у меня весь листинг простого примера ( http://pastebin.com/8x1AsSPk ) занял 3кб ( http://pastebin.com/Mh6zTJSG ) в отладочной версии. Прекрасно просматривается глазами.

Comment: Да более, менее читабельно, а как вы это получили? Из командной строки с /FA ключом запустили?

Comment: Можно /FAcs, можно в дереве проекта кликнуть на cpp-файле -> Свойства -> С/С++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output, там установить желаемое. После этого откомпилировать этот cpp-файл, в папке Debug (если собирается дебажная версия) появится одноименный файл и расширением ".cod".
Для g++ есть аналогичная опция, но я её не помню.